# Creating sf object from dataframe (UTM)

Tags: r, r-sf

I am new to the `sf` package in r attempting to create an object from a set of points gives to me in UTM by a collaborator. I've seen how people can use similar methods with lat/long coordinates but have not been able to achieve the same results because of the zone portion of point definitions

```
 can.df <- data.frame(
  rbind(
    c("NW",  "9V", 586518, 7077103),
    c("NE", "13W", 645544, 7118728),
    c("SW", "11T", 680262, 4865141),
    c("SE", "14T", 314095, 497555)),
    stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(can.df) <- c("Corner", "Zone", "Northing", "Easting")
## make xy numeric
num.cols <- c("Northing", "Easting")
can.df[num.cols] <- sapply(can.df[num.cols], as.numeric)
can.df["Zone"] <- as.character(can.df["Zone"])
test <- st_as_sf(can.df,
                   coords = c("Easting", "Northing", "Zone"),
                   epsg = 2955)
```

This will give me the error:

> Error in points_cpp(pts, gdim): Not compatible with requested type:
>   [type=character; target=double].

and if I strip the letters from the zone definition, and use it as numeric. Then I receive:

> Error in st_sf(x, ..., agr = agr, sf_column_name = sf_column_name): no
>   simple features geometry column present

Can anyone shed some light as to what I'm missing?

Comment: Are those coordinates all in EPSG:2955 (zone 11N) or does the `Zone` column indicate which UTM zone the coordinates are referring to?

Comment: @Spacedman thanks for catching that, the coordinates are not all within the same `zone` I would assume making my attempted use of that EPSG an oversimplification. Is there a way that I can read them in like this or will I need to create a more point-by-point based approach?

Comment: I think you'll have to go point-by-point, constructing an `st_point` object, working out the right EPSG code or PROJ string from the zone, and then transforming to a common CRS (eg 4326) if you want the lot in one `sf` data.frame. (also, do `can.df$Zone <- as.character(can.df$Zone))` to fix that column)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `"Zone"` form `coords` and change `epsg` to `crs`.  `epsg` is not a parameter accepted by `st_sf`.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.1, PROJ 6.2.0

can.df <- data.frame(
  rbind(
    c("NW",  "9V", 586518, 7077103),
    c("NE", "13W", 645544, 7118728),
    c("SW", "11T", 680262, 4865141),
    c("SE", "14T", 314095, 497555)),
  stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(can.df) <- c("Corner", "Zone", "Northing", "Easting")
## make xy numeric
num.cols <- c("Northing", "Easting")
can.df[num.cols] <- sapply(can.df[num.cols], as.numeric)
can.df["Zone"] <- as.character(can.df["Zone"])
test <- st_as_sf(can.df,
                 coords = c("Easting", "Northing", "Zone"),
                 crs = 2955)
#> Warning in lapply(x[coords], as.numeric): NAs introduced by coercion
#> Error in st_as_sf.data.frame(can.df, coords = c("Easting", "Northing", : missing values in coordinates not allowed

test <- st_as_sf(can.df,
                 coords = c("Easting", "Northing"),
                 crs = 2955)
test
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 2 fields
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 497555 ymin: 314095 xmax: 7118728 ymax: 680262
#> epsg (SRID):    2955
#> proj4string:    +proj=utm +zone=11 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
#>   Corner                         Zone               geometry
#> 1     NW c("9V", "13W", "11T", "14T") POINT (7077103 586518)
#> 2     NE c("9V", "13W", "11T", "14T") POINT (7118728 645544)
#> 3     SW c("9V", "13W", "11T", "14T") POINT (4865141 680262)
#> 4     SE c("9V", "13W", "11T", "14T")  POINT (497555 314095)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This answer seems only partially complete. Your solution sets all of the coordinates to have the UTM zone 11N. How would you create an sf object with the coordinates in appropriate Zones listed in the "Zones" column? Would you have to create a different sf object for each zone, convert them to a shared crs, and then merge them together?